# Run node-js from Java or Groovy

Tags: java, grails, node.js, groovy

anyone experimented on how to run node.js module or a script from java or groovy?

Could groovy command.execute() do it? If so then would it behave the same across different op sys.

Worth noting is that ideally, I would like that node.js would not be depended upon installation in the system and node command, but but packaged via ./configure and make, so that it could be used as a library..

Thanks

Edit: Basically I want this so that I could use node.js module, a client side framework(coffee-script, jade,stylus etc. And this is bundeled in Brunch), as a Grails plugin. So that the plugin is self-contained with no system dependency.

Comment: I dont understand why do people want to run nodejs from java, .net? First read what nodejs does and solves.

Comment: I don't know which other people you are referring to, but in this case, Jor wants consistent node.js across multiple platforms. I divined this from reading his question.

Comment: Say you have a big Grails app and a big nodejs library that you need - both with years of work implementing various APIs. Then you need to run nodejs from java.

Answer (score 9):

You might find what you're looking for in [vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/README.md).

From the site:

**What is vert.x?**

The next generation polyglot asynchronous application framework. (Formerly known as node.x)

- Runs on the JVM.
- Embraces the good bits of event driven frameworks like node.js then adds some even juicier bits.
- Everything is non-blocking.
- Polyglot. vert.x will be usable from multiple languages: Ruby, Groovy, Java, JavaScript, Python, Clojure, Scala. Currently we support Java and Ruby and have partial Groovy support. Write your code in the language you choose. Leverage the power of vert.x from that language.
- Goes with the recent developments with InvokeDynamic in Java 7 and bets on the JVM being the future premier runtime for dynamic languages.
- Enables you to create network servers or clients incredibly easily.
- True scalability. Unlike other well-known event-driven frameworks, you can have more than one event loop per process. No more spinning up 32 instances just to utilise the cores on your server.
- Incredibly simple concurrency model. Write your code as single threaded but watch it scale across multiple cores. No need to worry about race conditions or locks.
- Understands multiple network protocols out of the box including: TCP, SSL, HTTP, HTTPS, Websockets.
- Efficiently serve static files from the filesystem bypassing user-space altogether.
- Simple Sinatra/Express style resource based web routing.
- Distributed event bus. Multiple vert.x instances work together seamlessly to provide a distributed event bus
- SockJS support

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just command.execute()

A more elegant way might be to build a little node.js server that only accepts requests from localhost. But this groovy works:

```
    def file = new File("script.js")
    def fileStream = file.newOutputStream()
    fileStream << "console.log('hello from node.js');"
    fileStream.close()

    def command = "/usr/local/bin/node " + file.absolutePath 
    def proc = command.execute() 
    proc.waitFor()

    println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
    println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
    println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```